# Change obect type in class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have a class with a lot of helper methods.  I need to create either a serial connection or TCP connection when I instantiate an instance of the class.  I also need to keep a list of objects of this class.  IT's only the transport type that is different.

```
 Public Class CommsClass
       Public Property master As SomeClassFromElsewhere 'This clearly isn't right

       Public Sub New(host as String, port As String)
           master = New SpecificTCPClassFromElsewhere
       End Sub

       Public Sub New (comPort as String)
           master = New SpecficSerialClassFromElsewhere
       End Sub

       Public Sub Read
          master.Read()
       End Sub

       Public Sub Write()
          master.Write()
       Sub

    End Class

    Public Sub Main
       Dim masters as List(Of CommsClass)
    End Sub
```

I can use

```
Public Property master As Object
```

But I lose Intellisense in VS which I guess I could live with if I knew I was doing this correctly, but it just doesn't feel right.

I could also inherit two new classes (TCPCommsClass and SerialCommsClass) from CommsClass but that makes maintaining the list tricky.

Short of defining "master" as a generic object or creating a list of generic objects, is there a more elegant way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You have to declare that property as a specific type. If you want to be able to assign objects of more than one type to it, then the type of the property must be a class that appears in the inheritance hierarchy of each type you want to assign or an interface that each type implements. That's it, that's all. If `Object` is the only type that satisfies those requirements then `Object` is the only type you can declare the property as. It's not that you lose Intellisense but rather that Intellisense only provides members of the `Object` as they are all that is guaranteed to exist at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are optimising unnecessarily, and trying to have the CommsClass.Read() just call master.Read() - just wrapping a method for no reason.  Perhaps consider a factory method that takes a parameter that specifies whether it's TCP or Serial, then return a CommsClassTCP or a CommsClassSerial.  Both these classes inherit CommsClass.  Make CommsClass.Read MustInherit, then implement that in your CommsClassTcp and CommsClassSerial classes.  At some point, these classes must diverge, don't fight it.  Depending on what sort of comms you are doing, taking the Stream from TcpClient or SerialPort classes may be what you are after.

Comment: Apologies, I edited for brevity. The Read and Write methods do more than just call master.Read / master.Write.  Unfortunately I’m using a third party assembly that provides the root ‘someclassfromelsewhere’.  Also, if I do create two child classes, how do I create my kits and iterate through that list calling the Read or Write methods irrespective of the communication transport?

Comment: Consider a factory method that takes a parameter that specifies whether it's TCP or Serial, then return a CommsClassTCP or a CommsClassSerial. Both these classes inherit CommsClass.  Make CommsClass.Read MustInherit, then implement that in your CommsClassTcp and CommsClassSerial classes.

Comment: Also, if you do have TCPCommsClass and SerialCommsClass, maintaining the list shouldn't be tricky.  List(of CommsClass) - you could add member to that base class to indicate whether it's TCP or Serial.  Let me know if code required in answer.